# finder won't launch after Mojave upgrade ( high system cpu )

Tags: finder, upgrade, cpu, mojave

it appears my finder will not launch after I upgraded to Mojave. It is always unresponsive.  My system cpu load is constantly around 75% also.

I am unable to relaunch it even if I do a force quit from application monitor. Any ideas?

Also chrome will not render a webpage. Firefox and Safari work fine.

Comment: make that an answer for others to find

Answer (score 1):

It turns out was Google Drive File Stream syncing issue. I removed that and cpu is back to normal... https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8555291 no eta from Google though on when will be fixed?

a temporary work around by forcing Finder to reload the extensions needed for the context menu by opening terminal and issuing a

```
killall Finder
```

Comment: @Buscar웃, You said, "since websites sometimes change or diaper, ...", I guess someone has to "change" the "diaper", but the page can **disappear** too. :)

Comment: @user3439894 I am really glad having you watching over me as my personal proof reader.and spell checker. Keep up the good work. It helps me focusing on bigger issues and solving problems that matter.